# How to create an image link

Tags: images, links, facebook

Creating an image link in HTML is very simple by adding an image source to text. But it does not work on Facebook. After google online, anyimage.io is suggested to create an image link for a Facebook post. However, it even does not accept new images. So I ask this seemingly basic question, how to create an image link for a Facebook post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to create a post by copying the image address, then when the picture shows up hover the cursor over it and click on the trashbin and post.